# Finder: What are the keyboards shortcuts "Arrow down+Alt" "Shift+Arrow down+Alt" supposed to do

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, finder

Tonight, I discovered that the keyboard shortcuts "Arrow down+Alt" and "Shift+Arrow down+Alt" when used in Finder reopened older Finder windows.

As I sat a lot of keyboard shortcuts I thought there should be a problem.

I just wanted to find the keyboard shortcut that will let me select all the files/folders under the currently selected folder.

In forklift, "Shift+Arrow down+Alt" let me do that.

OS X version:10.10.

Answer (score 0):

A setting in DefaultFolder X I sat was replacing all the keyboard shortcuts of all my applications with keyboard shortcuts I sat for DefaultFolder X.

Case closed.